# Regex: combine statement with empty string

Tags: java, regex, whitespace, string

What I am trying to do: this regex should have to force the first character to be a letter, after that character, letters, a whitespaces or '-' can be inserted.

This first part works just fine: `(^[A-Za-z][A-Za-z -]*$)`

Then I would like to allow an empty string as well : `(^$)`

When I combine the two however, the user can start the string with a whitespace. What am I doing wrong here?
Thanx!

`(^[A-Za-z][A-Za-z -]*$)||(^$)`

(I don't know if this info is needed but I use this in Java, as part of a class that extends from InputVerifier, to set verifiers on JTextFields)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following should do it:

```
^([A-Za-z][A-Za-z -]*)?$
```

The `?` makes the expression inside the parentheses optional.

The reason your original regex isn't quite right is the `||`. The regex "or" operator is a single `|`. Now consider `x||y`. This matches `x` *or* an empty string *or* `y`. Since the empty string isn't in any way anchored, [`Pattern.find()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#find%28%29) will find at least one instance of it in *any* input.

Comment: I didn't understand your last statement. You mean to say: - `x||y` will even match a `whitespace`, and in fact any input?

Comment: but even with this pattern I can start with an empty character..
Maybe this has something to do with how the InputVerifier in Swing works?

Comment: @RohitJain: It will match absolutely anything.

Comment: @Rps: It's probably something to do with your code rather than the regex itself.

Comment: @NPE.. I am afraid, that is not really true. It would just match either `x`, `y` or an empty string. Try using: - `"  ".matches("x||y");`. This will probably give you false.

Comment: @RohitJain: OK, we're talking about different things, and are both right. Since the OP had `^` and `$`, this suggests to me that the regex is applied as a *search* rather than a *match*. I don't know whether that's in fact the case, but that the key to our misunderstanding.

Comment: @NPE.. Ah!! Now that makes sense. With `search`, it will of course match any string. I'll now re-upvote your answer.

Answer (score 4):

This one should suit your needs:

```
^([A-Za-z][A-Za-z -]*|)$
```

The `OR` in regular expressions needs only one `|`, while a classic JAVA one (amongst other languages) needs two `||`.

Comment: Ah! Didn't see this coming. +1 ;)

Comment: @Bohemian Yep, try `"".matches("^([A-Za-z][A-Za-z -]*|)$")`, it returns `true`.

Comment: @Bohemian.. It actually does.

Comment: Java has the one pipe `|` OR operator, too.

Comment: thx guys, but why am I still able to start with a whitespace?

Comment: @Rps.. Are you sure? It should not match a `whitespace`. Try: - `"  ".matches("^([A-Za-z][A-Za-z -]*|)$")`. Anyways, @NPE's answer is even better.

Comment: @jlordo Yeah, but the JAVA `|` hasn't the same meaning though.

Comment: In Java both `|` and `||` mean `OR`, but the latter has short-ciruit prevention. We shouldn't let this get too far off topic now :)